# Moving SSL certificate from one Heroku app to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate

I have an SSL certificate bought through DNSimple and it is already associated with a Heroku app. I am changing the domain to a new app. Is there any way to simply move the certificate and credentials from one app to the other?

Comment: I don't think Heroku will provide this as a first class feature since the use case sounds to be very limited, you might have to manually do it.